# python: treating a scalar as a one element list

Tags: python, list

I am writing a python script that process lists read from a file:

```
l = readListFromFile( myFile )
for i in l :
    # do something to each element
```

All works fine when `l` has more than one element.
However, when there is only one element in the list `readFromFile` returns `l` as a scalar and not as a list. Hence `for i in l` fails with error

> object is not iterable

**I have no control over `readFromFile`**, and my question is how can I make python treat `l` as a alist even in the case where `l` has only a single element?

Comment: what is the type of `l` when more than one items are returned. Is it a list or an iterator?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `l` is a list

Comment: You may not have control over the worker function, but you are free to rebind the name `readListFromFile` to do what it says it does, wrapping the underlying worker function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well a simple solution is

```
l = readListFromFile(myFile)
try:
    i = iter(l)
    if isinstance(l, str):
        i = l 
except TypeError:
    i = [l]
for .... in i
```

This will work even if you change what `readListFromFile` to return another iterable.

A one liner solution if it's guaranteed to be a `str` or a list (or other iterable) is just

```
l = readListFromFile(myFile)
for e in [l] if isinstance(l, str) else l:
```

just using a ternary operator.

On an aside, having a method called readList... not always returning a list is just evil.

Comment: Just be careful because strings are also iterable

Answer (score 3):

```
l = readListFromFile(myFile)
if isinstance(l, list):
    for i in l :
        # do something to each element
else:
    #do that something mentioned above
```

or

```
l = readListFromFile(myFile)
if isinstance(l, str):
    l = [l]
for i in l:
    #do that same something as above
```

or

```
l = readListFromFile(myFile)
try:
    for i in l:
        #do that something
except:
    #do that something with the value
```

and if you want a function:

```
def get_me_a_list(var):
    if isinstance(var, list):
        return var
    return [var]

l = get_me_a_list(readListFromFile(myFile))
for i in l:
    #do your something
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I was looking at something more elegant: like `for i in someMiracleThatAlwaysReturnsLists(l) : `

Comment: `isinstance(l, list)` is better.

Comment: Thanks - it's applied

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator function and `isinstance`:

```
def solve(lis):
   if isinstance(lis, list):
      for item in lis:  #use just `yield from lis` in py3.x
         yield item
   else:
      yield lis
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> for item in solve(1):
...     print item
...     
1
>>> for item in solve([1, 2, 3]):
    print item
...     
1
2
3
```

To handle any type of iterable you can use `collections.Iterable`:

```
from collections import Iterable
def solve(lis):
   if isinstance(lis, Iterable) and not isinstance(lis, basestring):
      for item in lis:  #use just `yield from lis` in py3.x
         yield item
   else:
      yield lis
```

Comment: There is a typo in the `solve()` parameter, it should be `lis`. Regardless of that, the OP said that he has not control over the function.

Comment: @Birei That's what the function is doing, it works for both integer and list.

Comment: Oh, sorry. My mistake, it's all fine. **EDIT**: I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the check directly into the for-loop:

```
l = readListFromFile( myFile )
for i in (l if isinstance(l, list) else [l]):
    # Do something with i
```

Answer (score 0):

If `readFromFile` returns a scalar rather than a `list`, then you can turn it to a `list` by yourself.

```
l = readListFromFile( myFile )
if not isinstance(l, list):
    l = [l]
for i in l :
    # do something to each element
```